# passport-google-oauth Failed to fetch user profile ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth

login via google on my meanjs website stopped working all of the sudden after three years, without any change to the code.
The request sent:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */
var passport = require('passport'),
  GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy,
  users = require('../../controllers/users.server.controller');

module.exports = function (config) {
  // Use google strategy
  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.google.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback: true,
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  },
    function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // Set the provider data and include tokens
      var providerData = profile._json;
      providerData.accessToken = accessToken;
      providerData.refreshToken = refreshToken;
      // Create the user OAuth profile
      var providerUserProfile = {
        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
        lastName: profile.name.familyName,
        displayName: profile.displayName,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        username: profile.username,
        profileImageURL: (providerData.picture) ? providerData.picture : undefined,
        provider: 'google',
        providerIdentifierField: 'id',
        providerData: providerData
      };

      // Save the user OAuth profile
      users.saveOAuthUserProfile(req, providerUserProfile, done);
    }));
};
```

this successfuly redirects to google consent screen, after login  the call back is fired:

```
  passport.authenticate('google', {},function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.redirect('/authentication/signin?err=' + encodeURIComponent(errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)));
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('/authentication/signin');
    }
.....
```

and returns the error "Failed to fetch user profile", this is the console.log of the err var:

```
{ InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\printer\mean-printer\node_modules\passport-google-oauth20\lib\strategy.js:99:19
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\printer\mean-printer\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js
:162:5)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  name: 'InternalOAuthError',
  message: 'Failed to fetch user profile',
  oauthError: { Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } }
```

Again saying, this started suddenly after working for 3 years. no code changes were made.

any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: We have the same problem which started when we added a second web application, served on a different port, but uses the same clientID, clientSecret and a different callbackURL (as there's a different backend service that handles it)

Answer (score 0):

Trying many things (including changing the oauth to version 0.10.0 vs. 0.9.x , suggested on several page... but that does not work)

The solution which worked was to change the Node version to 19 (18.12.0 and 18.12.1 face the issue).

Answer (score 0):

On node 18.12.1 same issue, upgrade to 19.2.0 fix this problem.
Probably downgrading to lower versions will fix it too.

Answer (score 0):

Node v16.13.2 is also affected by this.
**Some** of the requests would fail as you said with `Failed to fetch user profile`
Upgrading to Node v19 fixed the issue here as well.

Here's an issue for this bug: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

Upgraded to Node.js `lts/hydrogen` (v18.15.0-1 at the time of writing) and it seemed to do the trick.